# Docusign recognizes checkboxes, but can't interact with them through the API

Tags: java, docusignapi

I'm trying to create a document through the DocusignAPI. I'd like the user to be able to click on a checkbox, and set a validation so they have to click the checkbox.
When I upload the PDF to Docusign through the API, it will automatically recognize the checkbox and render it as a "tab". However, I'm not able to interact with the checkbox through the API to set a validation on it, or to change any other attributes.

My checkbox has a unique id and name, e.g. "TermsCheckbox". I've tried selecting for that id by using an anchorstring or a tab label. I've then tried to change the attributes of the checkbox to show I was able to select it. The checkbox does not change, which shows that I am unable to select it.

```
Checkbox termsCheckbox = new Checkbox();
termsCheckbox.setAnchorString("TermsCheckbox");
termsCheckbox.setSelected("false");
termsCheckbox.setName("hello terms checkbox");
termsCheckbox.setWidth("500");
termsCheckbox.setTabLabel("TermsCheckbox");
```

I don't see the checkbox change, meaning I'm unable to select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the actual checkbox object from the document.
So, the process is this:

1. Create an envelope
2. Upload pdf
3. do a GET call to get the envelope
4. Find in the json the checkbox
5. do a PUT call to update the checkbox

Let me know if it's not clear

Comment: To be clear -- Is there to no way to create an envelope with a checkbox? I would have thought there would be some way to get Docusign to find an HTML ID tag (e.g. `"TermsCheckbox"` and use that element.

Is the the only option to create the envelope, GET the envelope, add the checkbox, then PUT it?

Comment: yes, of course. but you had the checkbox created by pdf transform fields. Which means you didn't create it yourself. You can add any tabs you want with the API including checkbox. What I proposed is a way to do that after the envelope already has the checkbox created.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!